# Stop items showing before Masonry is initialised

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

I am trying to append Masonry elements to existing ones.

However, what I currently have is [this](http://comfyshoulderrest.com/shopaholic/demo/) - the items show before Masonry is initialised then jump into position a second later. I'd like them to be hidden until they're in position.

This is the code (within an infinite scroll plugin) that I'm using to append the Masonry items:

```
$container.append(data);
$container.imagesLoaded( function()
{
    $container.masonry('reloadItems').masonry();
});
```

And here it is being initialised:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $container = $('#container');
    // initialize the masonry instance
    $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $container.masonry({
            columnWidth: 1,
            itemSelector: '.item',
            transitionDuration: 0
        });
    });

    $('#container').scrollPagination({

        nop     : 36, // The number of posts per scroll to be loaded
        offset  : 0, // Initial offset, begins at 0 in this case
        error   : 'No More Posts!', // When the user reaches the end this is the message that is
                                    // displayed. You can change this if you want.
        delay   : 500, // When you scroll down the posts will load after a delayed amount of time.
                       // This is mainly for usability concerns. You can alter this as you see fit
        scroll  : true // The main bit, if set to false posts will not load as the user scrolls. 
                       // but will still load if the user clicks.   
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

Based on Josh's answer, my code now looks like this:

```
$container.append(data);
$container.imagesLoaded( function()
{
    $(".item").show();
    $container.masonry('reloadItems').masonry();
});
```

And I've added `<class='hide'>` to the item tag.

However, now no elements show up when I refresh the page.

Comment: I meant for you to hide items which are freshly brought into the page.
Your hiding everything so it is never showing.
Also, do a $('.item').removeClass('hide'); instead

Comment: That's the problem I'm having - how do I refer only to new items and not simply every `<item>`?

Answer (score 0):

Have them load with the bootstrap *hidden* class set, and remove it after masonry runs.

If masonry needs them to be visible to do its calculations, have them displayed off-screen when loaded. Z-index, crazy position, etc.

**Update**
http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html

So I gave a quick glance at methods here, without this trickery I talked about, I do believe you can ajax-load your new items, then use the masonry.addItems( items ) method.